# Save image to database MVC3

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a link like this: C:\folder\folder\image.jpg  . How can I save image to database in SQL Server?

If it was a HttpPostedFileBase I would knew how to save it, but now I have only a link.

- it's a link because I exctracted src tags from tiniMCE editor field .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example from msdn social:

table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FileStoreDemo](

                [id] [int] NOT NULL,

                [name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,

                [content] [varbinary](max) NULL,

                CONSTRAINT [pk_filestoredemo_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC))
```

code:

```
string filename = Server.MapPath("/Content/Desert.jpg")
using (fooEntities fe = new fooEntities())

{

    FileStoreDemo fsd = fe.FileStoreDemoes.CreateObject();



    fsd.name = new FileInfo(filename).Name;

    fsd.content = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

    fe.FileStoreDemoes.AddObject(fsd);



    fe.SaveChanges();

}
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlgetstarted/thread/1857938d-b74a-4954-bbde-734dfef08039

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Download and Upload Images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/)

Code is also available on [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140713/Download-and-Upload-Images-from-SQL-Server-via-ASP)

Comment: Thank you . I'll try Pushpendra answer first and then I'll read your link if it doesn't work .

Answer (score 0):

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(string fileTitle)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
                byte[] imageSize = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                file.InputStream.Read(imageSize, 0, (int)file.ContentLength);
                Image image = new Image()
                {
                    Name = file.FileName.Split('\\').Last(),
                    Size = file.ContentLength,
                    Title = fileTitle,
                    ID = 1,
                    Image1 = imageSize
                };
                db.Images.AddObject(image);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Detail");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("uploadError", e);
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: I got this error : 1.  http://imageshack.us/a/img836/1708/errorsyv.png   The code behind is this: 2. http://imageshack.us/a/img38/4279/code1.png

Comment: 1. Check model.content and Request.File[0] is not null. The code which I have given you that is work correctly when you are uploading a file from fileuploader and then saving it in to the database but I think you are using the imageSave code as a servie and there is also write down the different code for saving.